# Conditional formatting row of data based off of a date range

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, worksheet-function

I have a bunch of entries in a sheet which are all between a range of dates, the two columns with dates are `start_date` (B) and `end_date` (C).

I already highlighted past time periods using;

```
=DATEDIF($C2,TODAY(),"D")>0
```

This formats if the `end_date` is over 0 days ago.

---

I'm looking for a way to format if TODAY is between `start_date` and `end_date`. Like this, I can always highlight the current time periods entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
and(today()>start_date,today()<end_date)
```